# Angular - use local library

Tags: angular

I created two local libraries:

```
ng new my-library --create-application=false
ng generate library core
ng generate library shared
```

In shared library is used core:

```
import { CoreModule } from 'core';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SharedComponent],
  imports: [
    CoreModule
  ],
  exports: [SharedComponent]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

And I have angular application which has reference to both libraries:

tsconfig.json:

```
"paths": {
  "library/core": ["../library/dist/core/"],
  "library/shared": ["../library/dist/shared/"]
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {CoreModule} from 'library/core';
import {SharedModule} from 'library/shared';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When SharedModule doesnt have import CoreModule, I can build application successfully. But when SharedModule have import CoreModule:

> ERROR in ../library/dist/shared/fesm2015/shared.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core' in 'angular\library\dist\shared\fesm2015'

How to import local libraries to application? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you add it in the project `package.json` ? You need it in order to resolve dependencies :

```
  "dependencies": {
     "library/core": "file:core/dist"
  ...
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help

Comment: What is core/dist? The tolder is dist/core. Should I add this to package.json in shared library?

Comment: I don't know your real path to the your `core` build outDir, so by default I assume it was core/dist... Yes you have to put this dependency in your shared lib. I recommand to check this repo in order to find a good example of Angular libraries uses : https://github.com/FabianGosebrink/angular-libraries